# Is it possible to black-list/ban the [plugin-recommendation] tag?

Tags: discussion, support

I know removing it's not possible. But can it be blocked from being used?

Case in question (check the edit history): [How to add style to a string of text throughout WordPress website?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/89889)

Relevant meta: [Can tags or synonyms be blocked from being used or blacklisted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122545)

Comment: One idea I had was to merge [tag:plugin-recommendation], [tag:theme-recommendation] and [tag:hosting-recommendation] into a a *deprecated* tag `shopping-question`. Not sure about that.

Comment: I missed the [tag:feature-request] for this Q, but ain't sure of what can be done in-house... Hope other members jump in with their point of view.

Comment: Well, as I'm somewhat new here, I haven't gotten into the full depths of (WP)SE so far, but why shouldn't it be possible to 'disable' a tag? It could either not be suggested to the user when filling out the tags field, or it could just not be applied (meaning, if a user entered/selected this certain tag, it will be deleted before posting the question)...? However, as a user with enough reputation is able to create new tags, I don't know if this whole thing will work. Anyway, I do understand that providing `XYZ-recommendation` tags while not wanting that sort of question is counterproductive.

Comment: @tf Only SE employees can do that. But we need a visible consensus before we can ask for it. See also http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/338/why-wordpress-tag-on-wordpress-answers

Comment: I absolutely +100 the idea of merging them into [tag:shopping-question].

Comment: @toscho Could you move your comment to an answer, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could merge [plugin-recommendation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-recommendation), [theme-recommendation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme-recommendation) and [hosting-recommendation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosting-recommendation) into a deprecated tag `shopping-recommendation`, `link-recommendation` or something similar and add a good explanation to the tag wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was Facebook SE (could be confusing this though) that had it set to where you didn't include one of a few specific tags (fbql, facebook-graph, etc.) then it wouldn't allow you to post, instead putting an error message up at the top of the post creation page.

Could we do something similar, except the opposite? In other words, if some attempts to make a post with one of the *-recommendation tags, put up an error that states that the tags are not allowed and provides a brief explanation why.

Comment: Thanks all gods and goddess there is no http://facebook.stackexchange.com/, I'd be devastated by that :) . . . Will look for "forbidden tags" in [meta.se]. Here's one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19018/185667

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/... It's for FB developers, not users, and I don't see how it's any less meaningful that a site dedicated to WP.

Comment: Yup, it was just an unrelated rant... Just saw that facebook is the only one with SO domain, due to a collaboration between FB and SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171874/185667